# Hide "Share With" Menu from particular sub site

Tags: 2013, javascript, css, custom-actions

I want to hide following things from particular sub site.

1. I want to hide "Share With" menu from site actions

[image]

2. I want to hide "Share With" menu from Ribbon for list view "Item" or "Document" tab.

[image]

3. I want to hide "Shared With" menu from Ribbon for list item display form.

[image]

4. I want to hide "Shared With" menu from ECB menu for particular Item.

[image]

I am using SharePoint 2013. How can I achieve this? Is there any way using css,java script, etc? or may be hiding custom action decoratively?